# Remove focus from input on mouse click

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a input element of type radio.When element get focus through keyboard then it should display focus style but accessing element through mouse click should remove the focus.
I don't want to use js or jquery. I have this element implement on multiple page but I have a single shared css file for its styling.

```
<div class="radio">
 <input type="radio" value="button1">
 <span class="focus"></span>
</div>

css:
.radio{
  input{
     &:focus{
       ~ .focus{
         outline:1px solid red;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

My code didn't remove the focus on mouse click.

Comment: "I can't use js or jquery as I have this element implement on multiple page". Such a shame you can't use JS on multiple pages...

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to remove focus with a click when this is naturally the action people expect when clicking on an input?.. It would be helpful to see why you're trying to add this interaction.

Comment: Well my client wants that ..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
input {
    &:focus {
        outline:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work as I want visible focus on keyboard event but doesn't want it on mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you need focus when you select using keyboard. When you select using mouse, You want to remove focus.If that's the case,you can do that using  `tabindex`

```css
input:focus {
  outline: none
}
```

```html
<span tabindex="0">
      <input type="radio" value="button1" tabindex="-1">
</span>
```

Comment: By doing this radio button is not getting select using keyboard